# Oracle SQL table history

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

So this is the problem, I have a Oracle table, just a normal table with let's say 300 rows of data.

I need to figure out how that data looked like at least 100 days before, who made changes and timestamp would be nice also.
Thing is, I do have a schedule backup, but I believe someone changed data and removed backup, so I am trying to find out this change over system records.

I did google this and for results I got now, I didn't got what I needed.

- select * from dba_hist_sqltext - it gives me results for current session only
- SELECT SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ORA_ROWSCN) - specified number is not a valid system change number

Oracle SQL info -
Java(TM) Platform   1.7.0_51
Oracle IDE  4.0.0.13.80
Versioning Support  4.0.0.13.80

Do you guys have any other idea?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use flashback: [Using Oracle Flashback Technology](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_flashback.htm#g1026131)

With that, you can query using the `AS OF TIMESTAMP` clause, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable
  AS OF TIMESTAMP TO_TIMESTAMP('2004-04-04 09:30:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS');
```

This has to be enabled though, and there is a certain (configurable) size limit, so there is no guarantee that you can still query those records of 100 days ago. On a busy database the history may go back only a couple of minutes.

Comment: Thank you mate, it showed me in which direction to think about for finding the solution! Thanks once again for fast answer!